# Asp.net, C#, Linq and Array usage,

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, itext

```
var result = (from p in productInQuery
      join o in orderInfoQuery on p.refNo equals o.refNo
      join x in productQuery on p.productNo equals x.no
      join t in productOutQuery on p.no equals t.productInNo into productIn
      from t in productIn.DefaultIfEmpty()
      //let dateOut = (from m in orderInfoQuery where m.refNo == t.refNo select m.delivered).FirstOrDefault()
      orderby o.processDate descending
      select new
      {     
          modelNo = x.modelNo,
          mfgNo = p.mfgNo,
          serialNo = p.serialNo,
          poNo = p.poNo,
          lbs = p.lbs,
          width = p.width,
          height = p.height,
          depth = p.depth,
          qty = p.qty,
          dateIn = o.processDate,
          dateOut = (DateTime?)(from m in orderInfoQuery where m.refNo == t.refNo select m.processDate).FirstOrDefault()
      }).ToArray();
```

I want to add this result into iTextSharp table cell.

but I don't know how to do,

I tried,

```
int resultSize = result.Length;

/*
for (int j = 0; j < resultSize; j++)
{
    table.AddCell(result[j]);
}
*/

foreach (string[] test in result) //Error : Unable to cast object of type 
{
    int testSize = test.Length;
    for (int j = 0; j < testSize; j++)
    {
        table.AddCell(test[j]);
    }
}
```

but I lost way :(

anybody knows, please advice me~

[EDIT]

```
int resultSize = result.Length; //192
```

[image]

test does have a fields...

[EDIT 2]

Actually the result be returned from Model.

**PJ.WebUI.Models Reports Class**

```
public class Reports 
{
  public Array GetTransaction(){
    OrdersRepository ordersRepository = new OrdersRepository();
    var productInQuery = ordersRepository.ProductIn;
    var productOutQuery = ordersRepository.ProductOut;
    var productQuery = ordersRepository.Product;
    var orderInfoQuery = ordersRepository.OrderInfo;
    var result = (from p in productInQuery
      join o in orderInfoQuery on p.refNo equals o.refNo
      join x in productQuery on p.productNo equals x.no
      join t in productOutQuery on p.no equals t.productInNo into productIn
      from t in productIn.DefaultIfEmpty()
      //let dateOut = (from m in orderInfoQuery where m.refNo == t.refNo select m.delivered).FirstOrDefault()
      orderby o.processDate descending
      select new
      {     
          modelNo = x.modelNo,
          mfgNo = p.mfgNo,
          serialNo = p.serialNo,
          poNo = p.poNo,
          lbs = p.lbs,
          width = p.width,
          height = p.height,
          depth = p.depth,
          qty = p.qty,
          dateIn = o.processDate,
          dateOut = (DateTime?)(from m in orderInfoQuery where m.refNo == t.refNo select m.processDate).FirstOrDefault()
      }).ToArray();
    return result;
  }
}
```

And in controller call the method to get the result.

```
Reports reposrts = new Reports();
var result = reposrts.GetTransaction();

..

foreach (var test in result)
{
     table.AddCell(test.modelNo);
}
```

Then

```
Error   1   'object' does not contain a definition for 'modelNo' and no extension method 'modelNo' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So,

I move the model method into controller method (put all together in same method) and run. then it works!.

but the result be used in the other controller too. so I want to keep the result in Model class to reuse.

I want to know why it does not work if the result query is not in same method.

could you help me a little more please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does your code compile if you type `table.AddCell(test.modelNo);` even though its not visible in drop down? To me, it looks like that the Intellisense is not smart enough to get the fields the anonymous object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'result' will be an array of the anonymous type you selected to, not an array of string arrays, which is why you are getting an error in the foreach loop.

Your loop should probably look more like the following:

```
foreach (var test in result)  
{ 
    table.AddCell(test.modelNo);
    table.AddCell(test.mfgNo);
    table.AddCell(test.serialNo);
    // etc
}
```

@Edit 2:

Because the result of GetTransaction() is 'Array', the calling method has no idea what the type is, it just sees it as an array of objects, and, because it is an anonymous type, you can't (reasonably) cast it back to the expected type.

I think your best bet in this case would be to make a new class which has the properties you want to return, e.g.:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string ModelNo { get; set; }
    public string MfgNo { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
   // etc. - but with the correct types for the properties
}
```

Then change the linq query to select into this type, instead of the anonymous type, e.g.:

```
...
orderby o.processDate descending       
select new Transaction
{            
    ModelNo = x.modelNo,       
    MfgNo = p.mfgNo,       
    SerialNo = p.serialNo,
    // etc.
...
```

And change the return type of GetTransaction() from Array to Transaction[].

Comment: @a little sheep Thank you for ur answer! could you help me a little more please? please review my edited question~.

Comment: Is all the code above in the same method, or is it split up into different methods? If you have 'var result = <linq query>; foreach(var test in result) ...' in one method Intellisense should work fine.

Comment: @a little sheep Thank you! I'm so sorry but could you review my edited question one more time please? I want to learn exactly what was the problem..

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do but I believe you are casting each element of your result as a string incorrectly.

Try this:

```
foreach (var test in result)
```

You will probably need to tweak your inner code since test isn't an array, but that should get you past your current error.